# How to erase a canvas containing text with mouse

Tags: html, canvas, text, erase

I'm using the following code to erase a canvas with the mouse and reveal an image.

I'd like to add a logo and some text to the canvas. When the user hover over the canvas (the red layer), they will erase the text as well.

I'm not sure about what code I should add in order to achieve this.

Hope anyone can help!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
// set the canvas element's width/height to cover #wrapper
var wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper');
var wrapperStyle=window.getComputedStyle(wrapper,null);
canvas.width=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
canvas.height=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));
//
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // set "erase" compositing once at start of app for better performance
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

var canvasOffset = $("#canvasTop").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}



function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.stroke();
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
}

$("#canvasTop").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

```css
html, body {height:100%}
body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; cursor:default;}
#wrapper {
  position:relative; 
  margin:auto; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
}

#wrapper-image { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background: url('http://i43.tinypic.com/2iuvpf.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}

#canvasTop {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper-image"></div>
 </div>
 <canvas id="canvasTop" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

To load and draw an image on the canvas

```
var image = new Image();
img.src="imageURL";
image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
};
```

Assuming that ctx has been assigned a 2D context at time you load the image. That will draw the image in the top left corner, you may have to scale and center it.

To find out if the mouse has not moved (hovered) simply use `setTimeout` to call the erase function from inside the mousemove event listener. `setTimeout` returns a handle, you need to clear the current timeout by calling clearTimeout with the timeout handle before you create a new one. This way when the user hovers for whatever time the clear function will be called. Don't forget to clear the timeout if the mouse moves out of the canvas element or the current timeout will happen when the mouse is not over the canvas

For information on how to use setTimeout [MDN setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: Hi @Blindman67. I'd like to add a logo and some text to the erasable canvas. I'm not sure where I should add your code into mine?